# Oracle pl/sql case staement for different select statements in WHEN condition

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an CASE statement in pl/sql that doesn't work, looking for assistance.
I am not an Oracle person, a SQL person, so not quite understanding why this doesn't work. In SQL, something similar to the below would work fine, but apparently in Oracle I am missing something.

Just to be clear, I am trying to execute different select statements, depending on the WHEN condition. I've tried this in an IF block using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, but not sure if that is correct either.

This is the error I keep getting:

ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 186 Column: 42

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN (COUNT(*) > 0) THEN (SELECT id from MyTable)
        WHEN (COUNT(*) = 0) THEN (SELECT id from MyTable2)
    END
FROM TableA TA
        JOIN TableB TB ON TA.id = TB.id
        JOIN TableC TC ON TB.id = TC.id
        WHERE TA.id=1234;
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work in PL/SQL. Usually, we calculate number of rows returned and store it into a local variable (`l_cnt` in my example) and then - based on the outcome - use one `select` or another:

```
declare
  l_cnt number;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from tablea ta join tableb tb on ta.id = tb.id
                   join tablec tc on tb.id = tc.id
    where ta.id = 1234;
    
  if l_cnt > 0 then
     select max(id)
       into l_id
       from mytable;
  elsif l_cnt = 0 then
     select max(id)
       into l_id
       from mytable2;
  end if;
end;
```

There might be variations to it, depending on what you want to do with `id` you select. Note that - if number of rows in `mytable` or `mytable2` is different from exactly 1, you'll get an error (no_data_found or too_many_rows; that's why I included the `max` function - to avoid such errors).

What could you really do? For example, store ID values into a collection. Or use a cursor (`for` loop). Or ... who knows? As I said, depends on what you want to get as result.

---

Here's example which illustrates what you might do.

Sample table is Scott's `emp` (employees):

```
SQL> select deptno, count(*) from emp group by deptno;

    DEPTNO   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
        20          5
        30          6
        10          3
```

First, count will return *something* (as deptno = 10) and fetch values into collection:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_deptno    emp.deptno%type := 10;
  3    l_deptno_2  emp.deptno%type := 20;
  4    l_cnt number;
  5    l_col sys.odcinumberlist;
  6    --
  7    l_rc  sys_refcursor;
  8    l_id  emp.empno%type;
  9  begin
 10    select count(*)
 11      into l_cnt
 12      from emp
 13      where deptno = l_deptno;
 14
 15    if l_cnt > 0 then
 16       select empno
 17         bulk collect
 18         into l_col
 19         from emp
 20         where deptno = l_deptno;
 21
 22       for i in 1 .. l_col.count loop
 23         dbms_output.put_line('CNT > 0: ID = ' || l_col(i));
 24       end loop;
 25    elsif l_cnt = 0 then
 26       open l_rc for
 27       select empno
 28         from emp
 29         where deptno = l_deptno_2;
 30
 31       loop
 32         fetch l_rc into l_id;
 33         exit when l_rc%notfound;
 34         dbms_output.put_Line('CNT = 0; ID = ' || l_id);
 35       end loop;
 36    end if;
 37  end;
 38  /
CNT > 0: ID = 7782
CNT > 0: ID = 7839
CNT > 0: ID = 7934

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Next example will use refcursor (I'll modify department number in line #2, which is used in line #13):

```
SQL> l2
  2*   l_deptno    emp.deptno%type := 10;
SQL> c/10/99
  2*   l_deptno    emp.deptno%type := 99;
SQL> /
CNT = 0; ID = 7369
CNT = 0; ID = 7566
CNT = 0; ID = 7788
CNT = 0; ID = 7876
CNT = 0; ID = 7902

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: So if my SELECT statement returns multiple rows, that's a no deal in Oracle?

What I want is to execute different select statements based on the WHEN condition, and those select statements could each return multiple rows.

So like if WHEN condition1, the select statement could return 20 rows.
if WHEN condition2, the select statement could return a different 10 rows.

Comment: You CAN do that, no problem - re-read what I wrote (collection, cursor). Do you need an example?

Comment: Meanwhile, I posted example which shows what you might do. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about Oracle's programming language PL/SQL, but about Oracle's SQL implemantation. You are right, your query should be valid. The aggregation should return a count and depending on the count the query would either return the ID of MyTable or that of MyTable2 or NULL. (It should crash at runtime, though, if there is more than one row in MyTable or MyTable2, of course.)

Oracle obviously has a bug here. A workaround is to do this in two steps: Count the rows, then use this result and decide which ID to show.

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN cnt > 0 THEN (SELECT id FROM mytable)
    WHEN cnt = 0 THEN (SELECT id FROM mytable2)
  END
FROM
(
  SELECT count(*) AS cnt
  FROM tablea ta
  JOIN tableb tb ON ta.id = tb.id
  JOIN tablec tc ON tb.id = tc.id
  WHERE TA.id = 1234
) counted;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/FGdQyVpu